# Would like to use .fadeTo elegantly

Tags: jquery

Here's what I've got far, which works:

```
var X = $('#myID input:checked').length;
if (X) {
    $('input[name=Save]').show();
} else {
    $('input[name=Save]').hide();
}
```

What I'd like to do is write this elegantly using the .fadeTo method.

```
$('input[name=Save]').fadeTo(Y)
```

Where Y=1 if X > 0 AND Y=0 if X = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? It's not very elegant to read, but it's small (I haven't tested it, so tell me if it doesn't work):

```
$('input[name=Save]').fadeTo('fast', (X > 0) ? '1' : '0')
```

That random jargon stuff in the middle is basically what you originally wrote, but in a compact syntax. Here's a Wikipedia article about it, if you want to read it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript

Comment: I think I have to have 'fast' or 'slow' as the first argument, no?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want partial opacity, just use `fadeIn('slow')`/`fadeOut('slow')` instead of hide/show